# Python range variable error as not defined

Tags: python, function, variables, range

I am trying to code a repetitive polynomial function. It take an input vector a and an input b. I then use the value b to run for loop from 2 to that range. like if b is 50, it will run from 2 to 50. I apply it the vector to get a polynomial function as below. But when i try to use b in the range it says that b is not defined

```
def funct(a,b):
A = a
for i in range(2, b):
newrow = np.power(A,i)
a = np.vstack([A, newrow])
return a
```

So i tried adding this in the middle

```
b1 = int(b)
for i in range(2,b1)
```

it is still throwing that same error.
I am not sure how to define a variable in function input and to use that in range. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please fix the indentation first.

Comment: I'm not having any trouble, can you show how you call the function? (ps note that your loop goes to `b-1`)

Comment: I indented in the program. This is my first function. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As heeymal already suggested you need to indent the code inside your functions for it to work, an example

Yes:

```
def function_name():
    pass
```

No:

```
def function_name():
pass
```

Here is a snippet of the same code, I changed it up a bit and it works:

```
import numpy

def funct(a, b):
    A =a
    for i in range(2,b):
        newrow = numpy.power(A, i)
        a = numpy.vstack([A, newrow])
    return a
```

Python said that B is not defined because you were saying that b1 = int(b) without telling it what b actually is, as you did not indent correctly and that code was not considered part of the function. I recommend that you pay more attention to what what you're writing in it's current state your IDE would give you an error message saying that it expected an indent block.